# Why invoking operator() as a std::function does not work

Tags: c++, std-function

Consider this small class aimed to collect a sequence of strings:

```cpp
class issues_t final
{
 private:
    std::vector<std::string> m_issues;

 public:
    constexpr void operator()(std::string&& txt)
       {
        m_issues.push_back( std::move(txt) );
       }
};
```

I plan to use this as:

```cpp
issues_t issues;
do_something(issues);
```

This works:

```cpp
void do_something(issues_t& notify_issue)
{
    notify_issue("something");
}
```

But I'd rather like to consume this as:

```cpp
using fnotify_t = std::function<void(std::string&&)>;
void do_something(fnotify_t const& notify_issue)
{
    notify_issue("something");
}
```

This compiles but doesn't work: in the debugger the `push_back()` is executed but the underlining vector is not populated ([godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/f194zb7WW)), so what I'm missing here?

minimum reproducible example:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <print>

class issues_t final
{
 private:
    std::vector<std::string> m_issues;

 public:
    constexpr void operator()(std::string&& txt)
       {
        m_issues.push_back( std::move(txt) );
       }

    [[nodiscard]] constexpr auto begin() const noexcept { return m_issues.cbegin(); }
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr auto end() const noexcept { return m_issues.cend(); }
};

using fnotify_t = std::function<void(std::string&&)>;
void do_first(fnotify_t const& notify_issue)
{
    notify_issue("do_first");
}

void do_second(issues_t& notify_issue)
{
    notify_issue("do_second");
}

int main()
{
    issues_t issues;
    issues("main");
    do_first(issues);
    do_second(issues);

    for( const auto& issue : issues )
       {
        std::print("    {}\n", issue);
       }
}
```

Comment: Can you please put a [mcve] into the question? Godbolt is good and fine, but it's still an external, volatile resource.

Comment: Unless you need to save the function for later, I recommend you do what the standard library itself is doing: Using templates. That way you can use *any* callable object. For example `template<typename F> void do_something(F&& notify_issue) { notify_issue("something"); }`

Comment: `std::function` would work on a **copy** of `issues`... Use [`std::ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) to have expected output [Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xv1TnYxnr)

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt You're right, I'll add it as soon as I'm back in office for posterity.

Comment: @Jarod42 I can just upvote your helpful comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`do_something` accepts a `const&` which can bind to temporary objects.
When calling `do_something`, a temporary `std::function` object is constructed, and the `"something"` string is stored within the temporary `issues_t` it contains, not within the original `issues_t issues`.

Your design is prone to such mistakes, and working with templates and lambdas is likely more convenient:

```cpp
template <typename F>
void do_something(F f) {
    f("something");
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> issues;

    do_something([&issues](std::string&& s) {
        issues.push_back(std::move(s));
    });
}
```

More idiomatically, `do_something` should look like:

```cpp
// 1. constrain F to make sure f(...) actually works
template <std::invocable<const char*> F>
void do_something(F&& f) {
    // 2. use std::invoke to provide support for member functions pointers and
    //    other things where f() doesn't work
    // 3. perfectly forward f
    std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), "something");
}
```

Any one of these "improvements" (1, 2, 3) aren't strictly necessary, but more idiomatic.

Comment: Perhaps `[&issues](std::string&& s)` should be `[&issues](std::string s)` ?

Comment: @TedLyngmo [the recommended CppCoreGuidelines style for taking ownership of objects](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rf-consume) is to pass them by rvalue reference, and I tend to agree with that style because it prevents accidental copying.

Comment: Good thing I didn't edit that part too then. :)

Comment: I was previously using a template, I'm experimenting with `std::function` to avoid multiple definitions of `do_something()`-like functions for each possible notification mechanism, but I guess this just shifts complexity to another place.